# Mapping DateTimeOffset to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE in Oracle & NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, mapping, timestamp, datetimeoffset

I can't make NHibernate successfully map the native oracle "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" type to the CLR DateTimeOffset type.

It seems that Oracle chose to completely ignore the native DateTimeOffset type and is using their own proprietary type (OracleTimeStampTZ) in their ADO.NET provider. Since NHibernate is using native CLR types (like the DateTimeOffset type) - the Oracle ADO.NET provider fails any attempt to insert a row with such a type.

Do any of you have an idea how this issue can be solved ? I have to use the DateTimeOffset type since I need to record the timezone/daylight-saving offset in addition to the UTC value. The standard DateTime mapping won't cut it for me unfortunately.

Thanks in advance

Liron

Comment: you could implement an IUserType

Comment: I finally managed to do this without using a special user type. Instead I implemented a custom IEntityPersister class implementation that handled the conversions. I'll post the complete implementation once I'm done testing it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: uff ... IMO IEntityPersistor is much heavier to implement than IUserType, gratz for that

Comment: After viewing the example in http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html I tend to agree that IUserType should be far easier to implement. I'll try that when I have the time. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Could you mash up an answer explainig how did you solve it?

Comment: I second what quetzalcoatla says!!  (pretty) please add your resolution as an answer.

Comment: For future readers, I got this to (kind  of) work:   (with a Fluent (my custom subclass of ) FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap)                 Map(x => x.MyDateUtc).Not.Nullable().CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();  ... where MyDateUtc is property on the C# poco:    public virtual DateTimeOffset MyDateUtc { get; set; }
... I gleaned my code from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352719/save-and-load-utc-datetime-with-nhibernate         with oracle, it became a "TIMESTAMP(7)"...so this may lose information.  just sharing what i found ..