# NHibernate Date Format Issue for Converted Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have an app using NHibernate to connect to an Oracle database. I have been tasked with converting the Oracle DB to a SQL Server DB in such a way that switching between the DBs is as simple as changing the NHibernate drivers. In my Oracle DB I have a column defined as TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE. This column has been converted to a SQL Server datetimeoffset(6) data type. The mapping in my NHibernate hbm.xml file looks like this:

```
<property name="checkoutDate" type="DateTime">
      <column name="CHECKOUT_DATE" sql-type="TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE" not-null="false" />
    </property>
```

With this mapping I am able to insert a date into the table that shows up like this when I run a query in SSMS: 2018-05-24 10:48:17.000000 +00:00. However, when I try to query this table I get an two exceptions saying:

```
FormatException: Input string '5/24/2018 10:48:17 +00:00' was not in the correct format.
```

and

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Does anyone know a way to have NHibernate recognize the format of the datetimeoffset column without changing the sql-type in the mapping? Or is there a sql-type that I can use in the mapping that will work for both the Oracle and SQL Server column types?

Comment: Not sure about .NET, but in Java with Hibernate/JPA I would try to use DATE (it includes time with seconds in Oracle) or TIMESTAMP without time zone and store the dates in UTC, possibly with a separate column for the original time zone. That should work, though perhaps you need to use timestamp with time zone in your database?

Comment: I need to keep the time zone and adding a time zone column would require more changes to the app code than I would like. I am trying not to change the original Oracle DB but would consider it if there was another column type that stored the same amount of info as the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE type (date, time, and time zone).

Comment: In that case you probably need to write a user type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471940/mapping-datetimeoffset-to-timestamp-with-time-zone-in-oracle-nhibernate?rq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTimeType` NHibernate type expects to receive a .Net `DateTime` from the datareader, but SqlClient does yield a .Net `DateTimeOffset` when reading a SQL Server `DateTimeOffset`. Such a SQL type should be mapped with a .Net `DateTimeOffset`, using a `DateTimeOffset` NHibernate type.

(Yes, the error message you receives is a bit misleading, [it is emitted](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Type/AbstractDateTimeType.cs#L80) by catching the failure of `Convert.ToDateTime(rs[index])` where `rs` is a `DbDataReader`. In your case, with SQL-Server, `rs[index]` yields a `DateTimeOffset` which fails the conversion. The message should not mention `string` indeed.)

Since this was working with Oracle, I guess this means your Oracle client yields a `DateTime` when reading a `timestamp with time zone` type. This is quite unfortunate since this means losing the offset, but also this means `DateTimeOffset` .Net type cannot be supported with Oracle. (Well, the Entity Framework Oracle adapter seems to support it, so I guess it is still doable by reaching the Oracle specific `DbDataReader` implementation. But it is not doable by using just what `DbDataReader` exposes.)

So the trouble is that mismatch between Oracle and Sql-Server clients about types with a time zone/offset, the first yielding a .Net `DateTime` (by the way then, what purpose serves the offset in your application since the Oracle client does not transmit it?), the second yielding a .Net `DateTimeOffset`.

If, like in your example, you store everything in UTC, maybe should you consider declaring your column as a simple `datetime2(6)` on SQL-Server side.
If you need to retrieve it with its `Kind` correctly set as `Utc`, then additionally map it with NHibernate type `UtcDateTime`.

Otherwise, as [written by ewramner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518662/nhibernate-date-format-issue-for-converted-database#comment88073072_50518662), you need to use a [custom user type](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom) (a class implementing `NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType`). His link is about a user type for handling the .Net `DateTimeOffset` with Oracle. But in your case you would want instead to write a user type class with a `NullSafeGet` method checking what the data-reader does yield and converting it to `DateTime` if needed. Then in your mapping use it by supplying its assembly qualified name as the property type. (See a simple user type implementation [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate.Test/NHSpecificTest/EntityWithUserTypeCanHaveLinqGenerators/DoubleStringUserType.cs).)

Comment: You make a good point about the application not using the offset even though the DB is set up for it. So after playing around with a custom user type and not having the results I wanted, I decided to just change my SQL Server columns to DateTime2.